# How to get onTouch position on a Button using a top View?

Tags: android, view, gestureoverlayview

I have a custom View, which inherits from `GestureOverlayView`, and I want to log all the `MotionEvent` passed to this view.

It works well, but I can't get the `MotionEvent` when my gesture starts on an interactive layout widget (`Button`, `TextEdit`....)

Is there a way to bypass this behaviour?

Comment: Are you using custom widget class for Button and TextEdit ?

Comment: Nop, it's the base Android widget.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention any snipped code of yours,I make 2 different solution hopefully is help you
One way will be passing your widget to as `View` to method and call `OnTouchListener`

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {                      
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {                       
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{                      
                    break;
                }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Another way could be manually creating a MotionEvent using custom constructor
like this:

```
static public CustomMotionEvent obtain(long downTime, long eventTime, int action,
        float x, float y, int State) {
}
```

According to API

> Create a new MotionEvent, filling in a subset of the basic motion
>   values. Those not specified here are: device id (always 0), pressure
>   and size (always 1), x and y precision (always 1), and edgeFlags
>   (always 0).

[API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain(long,%20long,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int))

Comment: Thanks, but My goal is to not change the code of the widgets.
I'm developing a library which will bring my custom View, and background services.
I can't simply modify my Button code, here is the challenge.